# Ubicación Actual en Fragment con Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, google-maps

Estoy elaborando una app en kotlin, y requiero obtener la ubicación actual en un fragment.
He intentado usar el siguiente código, sin éxito.

class MapsFragment : Fragment() {

```
private val LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE = 1000
lateinit var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient

private val callback = OnMapReadyCallback { googleMap ->

    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(actual))
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(actual,18f))

    val task=fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation
    // checking location permission
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // request permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE)
        return
    }

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // request permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION), LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE)
        return
    }


task.addOnSuccessListener {alocation ->
            if (alocation != null){
                LatLng(alocation.latitude, alocation.longitude)
                var actual = LatLng(alocation.latitude, alocation.longitude)
            }
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "${alocation.latitude} ${alocation.longitude}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
```

Mi plan es usar esta ubicación actual, para ir desplazando el mapa al centro de la ubicación  actual del usuario.